# Run Chrome browser as another user via Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, runas

I am using Robotframework, Selenium2Library and Python to develop automated tests in an application that uses an automatic login (via AD).
And (as test requirements says) I have to open the Chrome browser with different users.

I can open with "Run As" command via .bat file or a simple command:

```
import os
cmd='C:\Windows\System32\\runas.exe /savecred /user:USRAUT "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe http://url"'
os.system(cmd)
```

This works to open browser but I cannot get/handle the browser in code to perform operations. I need to open it and "return" it to my code where I can handle it.

Can someone help me or give me some suggestions?

Regards.

Comment: do you need to have different sessions at the same time and interact with them or just one session per user per test?
if u don't need multiple sessions, on every test a new browser instance is created, so you don't need to worry about that

Comment: @JosePita yes I do have multiple sessions at the same time. With the same user or different users. This depends on the capacity of the slave/machine that is running the tests (in parallel).
But with only one session I am not able to use it if I open it "externally". It fails and says "no browser open", but the browser was open.

Comment: Have you tried starting the ChromeDriver with runas.exe and see if the spawned browsers are started under the other username?

Comment: @A.Kootstra how can I start chromedriver with runas.exe ? Path to chromedriver but adding the runas.exe call?

Comment: I have a similar doubt, were u able to get a solution for this @koxta

Comment: not yet @VincyMathew